# How to query BINARY fields in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to `SELECT` data from a table that stores Java UUIDs as `binary(16)`.

For example, the UUID `76572de1-aa8c-435b-afe4-8e260e19466b` looks like this in phpMyAdmin: `0x76572de1aa8c435bafe48e260e19466b`.

Now, how can I query any values from that table by using a simple string?:

- `SELECT ... WHERE uuid = '76572de1-aa8c-435b-afe4-8e260e19466b'`
- `SELECT ... WHERE uuid = '76572de1aa8c435bafe48e260e19466b'`
- `SELECT ... WHERE uuid = '0x76572de1-aa8c-435b-afe4-8e260e19466b'`
- `SELECT ... WHERE BINARY uuid = '76572de1aa8c435bafe48e260e19466b'`
- `SELECT ... WHERE BINARY uuid = '76572de1-aa8c-435b-afe4-8e260e19466b'`
- and a lot of other things utilizing `CONVERT` or `BINARY` keywords

Comment: Try [BIN_TO_UUID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_bin-to-uuid)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Hexadecimal literals in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html) look like this: `X'01AF'` or this: `0x01AF` (case insensitive in both cases.

One option would be `SELECT ... WHERE uuid = X'76572de1aa8c435bafe48e260e19466b'`

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that as well, but this just throws an Syntax error when trying to run that Query in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Just edited to remove the hyphens from the guid, which are not valid syntax of course

Answer (score 2):

Use [BIN_TO_UUID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_bin-to-uuid) and [UUID_TO_BIN()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-to-bin) functions.

```
SELECT ... WHERE uuid = UUID_TO_BIN('76572de1-aa8c-435b-afe4-8e260e19466b')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. At least on my current server the `BIN_TO_UUID` function is not defined, so I'm going with the `X'76572de1aa8c435bafe48e260e19466b'` approach.

Comment: If you already know the binary value, why didn't you just use what you have? `0x76572de1aa8c435bafe48e260e19466b`

Comment: what do you mean? The queries above aren't working, but it's working with the `X`.

Comment: I mean: `WHERE uuid = 0x76572de1aa8c435bafe48e260e19466b` - But never mind. Its the same as `X'...'`